# How to auto dismiss() or cancel() or hide() Datepicker after selecting the Date from the Datepicker dialog without the OK click button in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to dismiss() the Dialog of Date Picker after selecting the Date from the DatePicker, But I didn't get what I want, as well as I have search on google but unsuccessful. The below is the code I want to try to hide the Datepicker.

```
public static class DatePickerFragmentDepartureDate extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this.getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime() - (new Date().getTime() % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
        return dpd;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the chosen date
        TextView tv = (TextView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.departureDate);
        // Create a Date variable/object with user chosen date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
        Date chosenDate = cal.getTime();
        // Format the date using style and locale
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US);
        String formattedDate = df.format(chosenDate);
        formattedDate = (month + 1) + "#" + day + "#" + year;
        // Display the chosen date to app interface
        tv.setText(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Your answers and help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The `OnDateSetListener` on a `DatePickerDialog` won't be called until you click the OK button, which is why the answers below aren't working as you want. If you don't want the buttons provided by `DatePickerDialog`, why not just create your own `Dialog` with just a `DatePicker`, and set an `OnDateChangedListener` listener that dismisses the `Dialog`, too.

Comment: The idea is appreciable @MikeM. Let see what other people comments and answer.

Comment: OK, sure. I would mention, though, that if you want to stick with a `DatePickerDialog`, you'll need to find the `DatePicker` in it, and set your own `OnDateChangedListener` on that, so it's about the same amount of code, either way.

Comment: Yeah stick with the DatePickerDialog because it is the requirement, so finding the best suitable solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class DatePickerFragmentDepartureDate extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

DatePickerDialog dpd;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this.getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime() - (new Date().getTime() % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
            return dpd;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the chosen date
            TextView tv = (TextView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.departureDate);
            // Create a Date variable/object with user chosen date
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
            cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
            Date chosenDate = cal.getTime();
            // Format the date using style and locale
            DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US);
            String formattedDate = df.format(chosenDate);
            formattedDate = (month + 1) + "#" + day + "#" + year;
            // Display the chosen date to app interface
            tv.setText(formattedDate);

            if(dpd != null){
               if(dpd.isShowing()){
                  dpd.dismiss();
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't dismiss the dialog when I select the Date, I still need to click on the OK button, which I don't want to click. @AndroidLovers